# making function lazy in Python

Tags: python, lambda, lazy-evaluation

I want to write a wrapper function for `eternity` that will make it behave as if it's being lazily evaluated. In other words, its functionality should be made identical to that of the function `lazyeternity` below. I have this function `packageN` that takes a function and packages it into a lambda--or at least I think it does. (Packaging `lazyeternity` inside a lambda delayed its evaluation in the call of `etest`.) How can I modify `packageN` so that `eternity = packageN(eternity)` can mirror the behavior of `lazyeternity`?

```
    def eternity():
        return eternity()

    # How can I create a wrapper function for eternity...
    # that will make it behave identical to this function?
    def lazyeternity():
        return lambda: lazyeternity()

    def packageN(f):
        return lambda *x: f(*x)

    def etest(x, y):
        return x

    eternity = packageN(eternity)

    # I want these both to return 4.
    # Currently only the first one returns 4,...
    # because the second one evaluates the eternity()...
    # parameter forever. I want to delay the evaluation...
    # of the parameter.
    print etest(4, lazyeternity())
    print etest(4, eternity())
```

Comment: Can you add a more specific example of how you want to use this? The code in your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Thanks, @Håken. I tried to clarify a bit, but let me know if I can be of more help. I want to be able to apply `packageN` to any function `f` to make it so that `f` is evaluated only when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `lazyeternity` and `eternity` as returned by `packageN` is that calling `lazyeternity` returns a lambda, whereas `eternity` *is* a lambda which, when called, runs forever.

To make `packageN` return something that acts like `lazyeternity`, make it

```
def packageN(f):
    return lambda: lambda *x: f(*x)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, this works!! But wasn't `packageN` returning a lambda before? If I print `eternity` after running `eternity = packageN(eternity)` using either my version of `packageN` or your version, it says the object is a lambda.

Comment: `packageN` was returning a lambda, which is assigned to `eternity`, so calling `eternity` executed that lambda. As opposed to calling `lazyeternity` which just gives you a lambda (and doesn't execute it). So to do the same, `packageN` must return a lambda which returns a lambda.

Comment: Would this work with higher-order functions? I'm trying to wrap the lazy definition of the Y combinator, def Y(f): return f( Y(f) ) in such a way.

Comment: Sure, why not? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

To make both `eternity` work, simply remove the `()`. You want to return a function, not the evaluation of a function (infinite loop).

Comment: `eternity` is not supposed to work in the context of `etest`. I want a wrapper function to modify it so that `etest` can work with `eternity` as an argument if `eternity` is not being used (i.e. it is the second argument in `etest`).